# Add js script in Laravel-blade file?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade, vite

I have a Auth module of nwidart/laravel-Module. I want to add script file in **Modules\Auth\Resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php** file
That is how i am doing it

```
<body>
......
...

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

but when i run this code i get this

> **Error:** GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
> This is my vite.config.js file

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'Modules/Auth/Resources/css/app.css',
                'Modules/Auth/Resources/assets/js/app.js'
              ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

I dont know what i am doing wrong.

Tried
 `<script src="{{ asset(/js/app.js) }}"></script>`
but nothing worked

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#working-with-blade-and-routes)? Looks like you should be using `Vite::asset()`.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work you have to do some changes.

Change

```
<script src="{{ asset(/js/app.js) }}"></script>
```

To

```
@vite('Modules/Auth/Resources/assets/js/app.js')
```

Anf if you want your css file to be loaded with vite then you can pass another file in vite directive.

```
@vite(['Modules/Auth/Resources/css/app.css', 'Modules/Auth/Resources/assets/js/app.js'])
```

For reference I am adding link to [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#loading-your-scripts-and-styles).